# MySQL query to JPQL for multi join SpringBoot + JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, hql, jpql

I have a mysql native query, how to convert same mysql to JPQL as i am using JPA and Springboot in my project.

here is the mysql query and working perfectly:

```
select title0_.title_id as title_id1_15_, title0_.title_categorystudio_id as title_ca3_15_, title0_.title_name as title_na2_15_ 
from title title0_ 
    inner join title_language languages1_ on title0_.title_id=languages1_.titlelanguage_titleid 
    inner join language language2_ on languages1_.titlelanguage_languageid=language2_.language_id 
    inner join title_genre genres3_ on title0_.title_id=genres3_.titlegenre_titleid 
    inner join genrescategory genrescate4_ on genres3_.titlegenre_genreid=genrescate4_.genrescategory_id 
    left join (movie movies5_  inner join studioname studio8_ on movies5_.movie_studio_id=studio8_.studioname_id) on title0_.title_id=movies5_.movie_titleid 
    left join (tvshow tvshows6_ inner join studioname studio9_ on tvshows6_.tv_studio_id=studio9_.studioname_id) on title0_.title_id=tvshows6_.tv_titleid 
    left join (kid kids7_ inner join studioname studio10_ on kids7_.kid_studio_id=studio10_.studioname_id) on title0_.title_id=kids7_.kid_titleid 
    inner join categorystudio categoryof11_ on title0_.title_categorystudio_id=categoryof11_.categorystudio_id 
where 1=1
and (language2_.language_name in ('english')) 
 and (genrescate4_.genrescategory_name in ('action')) 
 and (categoryof11_.categorystudio_title in ('tv')) 
 and (studio8_.studioname_name in ('sony') or studio9_.studioname_name in ('sony') or studio10_.studioname_name in ('sony'))
```

I am using a JPQL query which not working,

```
@Query("select t from Title t " +
            "join t.languages l " +
            "join t.genres g " +
            "left join t.movies m join m.studio ms " +
            "left join t.tvShows tv join tv.studio tvs " +
            "left join t.kids k join k.studio ks " +
            "join t.categorystudio c  where l.languageName IN (:languages) AND g.name IN (:genres) AND c.categorystudio_title IN (:categories)  AND (ms.name IN (:studios) OR tvs.name in (:studios) OR ks.name IN (:studios))")
```

in Logs the JPQL query is displaying as:

```
select title0_.title_id as title_id1_15_, title0_.title_categorystudio_id as title_ca3_15_, title0_.title_name as title_na2_15_ from title title0_ 
    inner join title_language languages1_ on title0_.title_id=languages1_.titlelanguage_titleid 
    inner join language language2_ on languages1_.titlelanguage_languageid=language2_.language_id 
    inner join title_genre genres3_ on title0_.title_id=genres3_.titlegenre_titleid 
    inner join genrescategory genrescate4_ on genres3_.titlegenre_genreid=genrescate4_.genrescategory_id 
    left outer join movie movies5_ on title0_.title_id=movies5_.movie_titleid inner join studioname studio6_ on movies5_.movie_studio_id=studio6_.studioname_id 
    left outer join tvshow tvshows7_ on title0_.title_id=tvshows7_.tv_titleid inner join studioname studio8_ on tvshows7_.tv_studio_id=studio8_.studioname_id
    left outer join kid kids9_ on title0_.title_id=kids9_.kid_titleid inner join studioname studio10_ on kids9_.kid_studio_id=studio10_.studioname_id 
    inner join categorystudio categoryof11_ on title0_.title_categorystudio_id=categoryof11_.categorystudio_id 
where (language2_.language_name in (?)) and (genrescate4_.genrescategory_name in (?)) and (categoryof11_.categorystudio_title in (?)) and (studio6_.studioname_name in (?) or studio8_.studioname_name in (?) or studio10_.studioname_name in (?))
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "not working" ... ?

Comment: yes... it's resulting empty json array [ ]

Comment: @BillyFrost what wrong in the JPQL query which is different from mysql query?

Comment: You are missing the subquery implementation like `... left join (movie movies5_  inner join studioname studio8_ on movies5_.movie_studio_id=studio8_.studioname_id) on title0_.title_id=movies5_.movie_titleid 
    left join (tvshow tvshows6_ inner join studioname studio9_ on tvshows6_.tv_studio_id=studio9_.studioname_id) on title0_.title_id=tvshows6_.tv_titleid 
    left join (kid kids7_ inner join studioname studio10_ on kids7_.kid_studio_id=studio10_.studioname_id) on ...` and also the values for the ? `where (language2_.language_name in (?)` .

Comment: @Arihant  Values will pass as we give .. it just shows the query looks in the log.. how to do that subquery implementation in JPQL